# number_to_currency locale converting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, locale, number-to-currency

Why does `number_to_currency(33.50, :locale => :fr)` displaying $33.50?  It should display it in different currency based on the locale.  I would expect a result of `33,50 €`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For this to work you need to have a locale file at `config/locales/fr.yml`. You can get it from here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml.

The `:locale` option only declares to Rails what locale you want it to be. Rails does not have all the translations for every language in the project, and so you must include these translation files yourself.

Answer (score 53):

I know this is a bit late. But just wanted to expalin the above answer.
Use it as following:

```
number_to_currency(aNumber, :locale => :fr)
```

This uses the file `config/locales/fr.yml`.
You can form your own currency format and define it in `config/locales/fr.yml`. The File will contain the following:

```
fr:
   number:
     currency:
        format:
          unit: '€'
          delimiter: ','
          separator: '.'
          precision: 2
          format: '%n%u'
```

`unit` is the currency Symbol.
also you can format the whole string with the `format:`.
More on this [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001684)