# Formatting currency for i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In config\application.rb  I added this line of code:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

And then I wrote something for test in a view like this, BUT it is still formatting the money in US dollars. Shouldn't it be formatting it by the locale I gave to it?

```
<p>woo! I have this much money: <%= number_to_currency(9800.56) %></p>
```

Comment: Do you have a locale file at: `/config/locales/de.yml`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-problem

Comment: no, Oh I was thinking the method will take care of it? So I still need the yml file?

Comment: Yes, you can get it [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml).  If the locale file can't be found, rails assumes that it won't have the required info and reverts to using 'en'.

Comment: you can post it as answer too if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a 'de' locale installed at `/config/locales/de.yml` for this to work, you can get it [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml). If the locale file can't be found, rails assumes that it won't have the required info and reverts to using 'en'.  See similar problem at [number_to_currency locale converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-problem).