# Convert comma to point as delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, delimiter

How can I convert user number input from something like 11,5 to 11.5?

I have tried the following as callback:

```
before_validation :comma_to_delimiter

def comma_to_delimiter
  self.price.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
end
```

But this doesn't work. I want the user to be able to type in whatever he wants as delimiter - currently, the app throws an error when the user uses a comma instead of a point.

Comment: Can you explain what type of value self.price is?

Comment: You want to change this for display in rails app, right?

Comment: No, I don't care about how it is displayed. I have taken of that through locales. Price is a float value that should be stored as float with point as delimiter. The issue is that in Germany, people type in commas rather than points as delimiter. So even if a German person types in "5,5", it should still be stored as "5.5". And if someone types it in correctly in the first place, such as "5.5", nothing has to be changed. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're doing may not be the best way, so perhaps someone can answer with a better approach. But to get your line working you need to make it actually persist the change.

```
self.price.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
```

Will just return the change, but that doesn't go anywhere in a callback!

```
self.price = self.price.to_s.gsub(',', '.').to_f
# OR
self.price.to_s.gsub!(',', '.').to_f
```

Will persist the change within the object.

Comment: The second version will not change the value of self.price

Comment: I've run the code locally and it most certainly does, have you tried it? Tested and works exactly as described in Rails 3.

Comment: Yes just realised, if self.price is already a string, then it will change. I was going on the assumption that it was a floating point number (may have misunderstood the question!)

Comment: It doesn't save numbers after comma. If `5,75`, saves `5.00`. Or is it just for me? Thanks!

Comment: same problem as @Gediminas I can't do it in the model. The number is truncated. This is probably due because the number is entered in a form and appears as a string. When it reaches the model the conversion is done like `"5,5".to_f` which truncates the number decimal part. Seems like the hooks (`before_validation`..) all happen after the type of the field is applied. Then I have done the change in controller..

Answer (score 14):

In some countries comma is the standard currency delimiter and if a user types "19,99" into a form it will be saved as "19.00" unless you handle the delimiter conversion manually. I think the right way to solve this is to write custom attribute setters.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def price=(val)
    val.sub!(',', '.') if val.is_a?(String)
    self['price'] = val
  end
end
```

Comment: Would be nice to handle this globally for all float attributes.

Comment: @Vassilis any idea on how to handle that globally?

Comment: @BenjaminJ.Benoudis I think the most proper way is to use a helper... number_to_currency(1234567890.50, separator: ".", delimiter: ",")

Comment: @BenjaminJ.Benoudis number_to_currency also supports i18n which means that you can setup the format globally in a yml file. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-locale-converting

Comment: @Vassilis thanks, but it's not for displaying, but for accepting numbers with comma, and numbers with dot in an input form. I don't find any global easy solution.