# number_to_currency rails fails with comparison of String with 0 failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, number-to-currency

i'm using `rails 3.2` and `ruby 1.9.3`
i'm using this to display a price:

```
number_to_currency(12.0)
```

in locale :en, it works but in :es I get:
`comparison of String with 0 failed`

didn't find it anywhere, anyone?

edit: I have updated the number just to be clear, the number is legal, the problem is with the locale

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842529/number-with-precision-return-integer. Also do check the return value's class of order[:base_price], '1' > 0 would fail with the error: comparison of String with 0 failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicated question with this one [number_to_currency locale converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-locale-converting)

Try adds the es.yml in your locale and try again.

Answer (score 3):

There can be another explanation to this error when the locale file actually exists.

Make sure that numbers are not quoted in your locale file.

i.e.

```
es:
  number:
    currency:
      precision: 2    # correct
      precision: "2"  # that would be wrong
```