# ActiveAdmin number_to_currency helper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, activeadmin

I building a administration interface via **ActiveAdmin**. I have some resources like Products, at the Products i have an Article, Title, Description and Price columns. Everything working well, but i have a little problem, at the Price column i use helper **number_to_currency**, by default ActiveAdmin display currency as **USD**. I want to display prices in local currency, so and here i have a question how to implement this helper to display price in local currency (for example FR, AUD or RUB).

---

**Rails 4.1.0**

**ActiveAdmin 1.0.0**

**ruby 2.1**

---

**app/admin/product.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

    # Permitted parameters
    permit_params :article_id, :title, :description, :price

    # Displayed columns
    index do
        column :article, :sortable => :article
        column :title
        column :description
    # Currency helper
        column :price, :sortable => :price do |cur|
            number_to_currency cur.price
        end
        default_actions
    end
end
```

**app/models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationship
    belongs_to :article

    # Validations
    validates :article, :title, :description, :price, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `:locale` parameter. From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency):

> Options
>
> ---
>
> :locale - Sets the locale to be used for formatting (defaults to current locale)

...snip...

> ```
> number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)      # => 1 234 567 890,51 €
> ```

To add support for a locale you need to have a `<locale>.yml` under `config/locale`, for example:

ru.yml

```
ru:
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        delimiter: ! ','
        format: ! '%n %u'
        precision: 2
        separator: '.'
        unit: руб.
```

Comment: sorry, i need to implement this inside a app/admin/product.rb or ill need to make a helper file and put require inside app/admin/product.rb ? Also thanks a lot for your help again ;)

Comment: This is built into the `number_to_currency` API (see the link) - all you need to do is add locale information to its call (`number_to_currency cur.price, locale: my_locale`)

Comment: Mister are you wizard. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: hmmm maybe its weird but nothing is going on i still see USD

Comment: What locale are you setting? you can test it in `rails c` before running it on your server

Comment: already tried **number_to_currency cur.price, locale: :fr** and **number_to_currency cur.price, locale: :ru** and still see a USD

Comment: also i tried do define ru.yml in config/locales/
**ru:
   number:
     currency:
        format:
          unit: 'руб.'
          delimiter: ','
          separator: '.'
          precision: 2
          format: '%u%n'**
and i still see prices in USD :)

Comment: this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-locale-converting ?

Comment: Add the following files - it worked for me: ru.yml: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/master/rails/locale/ru.yml; fr.yml: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/master/rails/locale/fr.yml

Comment: its kind of buggy stuff because i copied this to **ru.yml** in **/config/locales** after that in **app/admin/product.rb** i call **I18n.locale = :ru** locales applies for everything but not for this Price column, its so weird

Comment: I've created the following ru.yml, which works for me: https://gist.github.com/uriagassi/5f448b7712817653b507

Comment: wicked! it works!
Also i've **call number_to_currency cur.price, unit: 'руб.'**, and its works too, 
but have another problem )) currency sign now displays before value, i need that it displays after value

Comment: wicked! now everything is working properly. Uri, Thanks a lot for your time.