# Storing multiple currencies in Postgres, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, currency

I have a rails app which deals with product prices from different countries.
Storing GBP, and USD is working fine. However, when I start to deal with the CLP (Chilian peso) which has 3 decimal places, it's not storing right.

For example, I am trying to insert 799.990 but when it goes in its storing as 799.99. It is not ideal as there could be a price of 799.99.

I have the price set to `t.decimal :price, precision: 19, scale: 4` so this should cover most currencies.

So, my question is there any way to store the price with the trailing 0? Or am I missing something, is there a better way to deal with currencies in rails?

---

Update: 
After searching a bit more on StackOverflow, I think this may be an easier way of dealing with currencies.

[number_to_currency locale converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237592/number-to-currency-locale-converting)

Answer (score 1):

As 799.99 is same as 799.990 in terms of the amount, you **don't** need to modify the database column to store the trailing "0". You can simply edit your view to display 3 digits after decimal:

```
<% if @product.currency == 'CLP' %>
  Price: <%= '%.3f' % @product.price %>
<% else %>
  <!-- Existing logic -->
<% end %>
```

**Update**

Another option is to use [`sprintf`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf):

```
<%= sprintf('%.3f', @product.price) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jagdeep already wrote in his answer, you only need to format the number when you render it to a page.

I would use Rails' [`number_to_currency`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) helper for this:

```
CURRENCY_OPTIONS = { 
  'CLP' => { unit: '$', precision: 3 },
  'EUR' => { unit: '€', precision: 2 },
  'USD' => { unit: '$', precision: 2 } 
}

number_to_currency(price, CURRENCY_OPTIONS[currency])
```